# MathJax not working in Blogger

Tags: blogger

Since MathJax cdn is shut down, I did this:

[image]

I got this:

[image]

Is there any way to make MathJax work in Blogger? If not, are there any good alternatives?

Comment: What results should you have gotten?  Does that script file work from somewhere outside of Blogger?

Answer (score 1):

Try linking to the current version of MathJax, without any parameters, and see if that works:

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.3/MathJax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Some other CDNs that host MathJax include:

- [jsdelivr.com](https://jsdelivr.com/)
- [unpkg.com](https://unpkg.com/)
- [rawgit.com](https://rawgit.com/)
- [gitcdn.xyz](http://gitcdn.xyz/)
- [raw.githack.com](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/raw.githack.com)

(This list is from the [MathJax docs](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/start.html#mathjax-cdn).)

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different version (from [here](https://www.airinaa.com/2018/04/add-mathjax-beautiful-mathematic.html)) to free yourself from version numbers is this:

```
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.5/latest.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML' async></script>
```

That said, I've spent the last two days trying to get MathJax working in Blogger without success. I've put the scripts in the  block, and I've put it "in line". I've tried different versions without success. I've seen references from 5+ years ago that clearing the browser cache can make a difference.

The blog page does render properly in MS Edge. I'm not sure if that implies that the page itself is OK, or not.